# Link buttons on a custom Wix website are not navigating to their respective destinations from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, url, hyperlink, velo

**BackGround:**

I made a website using wix.com that is this[https://www.igparrot.com]. I embedded this website in our iOS app in Xcode. When I access the website from the browser, any link or button redirecting to other URLs outside the website are working fine but when I open them from the app, those link buttons are not navigating to the specified URLs. Basically no action is taken.

**Code:**

Here is the code from where I'm passing the website URL:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 
{
return ("Support".localized(), "https://www.igparrot.com")
}
else if indexPath.row == 1 
{
return ("Rate the App".localized(), "https://apps.apple.com/app/id1522248373")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a `WKWebView` to present your webpage, the webpage is presented and links on this page aren't working. Have you implemented the `WKNavigationDelegate` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate)). to handle links? Perhaps something's going wrong in how you've implemented the delegate. From the `WKWebView` documentation:

> When the user clicks a link in your content, the web view acts like a
> browser and displays the content at that link. To disallow navigation,
> or to customize your web view’s navigation behavior, provide your web
> view with a navigation delegate — that is, an object that conforms to
> the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol. Use your navigation delegate to
> modify the web view’s navigation behavior, or to track the loading
> progress of new content.

Specifically, the `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)` should be interesting for you, as this enables you to decide whether to visit a page or not in your `WKWebView`.

Example:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {
        if host.contains("example.com") {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
    }

    decisionHandler(.cancel)
}
```

Also, check [this page](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-control-the-sites-a-wkwebview-can-visit-using-wknavigationdelegate) for more information.

It could also be the case that the pages you're linking to are `http://` instead of `https://`. Sites with the former are blocked by default (for security reasons). If you want to enable them (*not recommended*) you could do this by adding this to your `Info.plist` file:

```swift
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Another reason could be that you've configured the `WKWebViewConfiguration` in a way that you only allow linking to pages that are so-called *app-bound domains*. Then the setting of `limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains` is set to `true` and it only allows domains you have listed in your `Info.plist` (see below). If a page link is not at one of these domains, it won't work. If the setting is `false`, you don't need to add them to the app-bound domains.

```swift
<key>WKAppBoundDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>example1.com</string>
    <string>example2.org</string>
    ...
</array>
```

Comment: Hi @Bjorn, Yes I’m using WKWebView. But my question is: “In this url https://www.igparrot.com I have some buttons in it like Facebook button, Instagram Button etc. This URL is working properly when I open it through WKWebView but on opened URL, when I press the buttons which are in url are not navigating to specified URLs. For example, when I press the Facebook button then nothing happens.

Comment: I used your approach, but according to your approach, it only checks host of main url, not the urls that are inside the webpage (eg: Facebook url,instagram url)

Comment: You'd need to add multiple hosts in that case and check for all of them.